# Errors, strange partition allocation: can I recover?

Tags: partitioning, system-monitor, clonezilla, gnome-disk-utility

New Ubuntu 18.04 installation, meant to replace an Ubuntu 16.04 that I used intermittently for several years.

Tonight I was trying to clone the disk with Clonezilla, but I got some error copying sda5. I rebooted Ubuntu from Clonezilla and got another weird (fatal) error. I rebooted again, directly, and found that something bad has happened to the filesystem.

The system disk should be partitioned like this:

```
Device     Space   Type     Contents
/dev/sda1  109 GB  NTFS     Windows 10 system disk
/dev/sdb2   20 GB  NTFS     Auto mounted data disk
/dev/sdc3  119 GB  ext4     Ubuntu
```

Disks says that instead it is like this:

```
Device     Space   Type     Contents
/dev/sda1  109 GB  NTFS     Windows 10 system disk
/dev/sda2   21 GB  NTFS     Not mounted
/dev/sda3    0 GB  Unknown  Disks says "--"
/dev/sda4  119 GB           Unallocated space
```

Yet Ubuntu does boot.

I tried to use System Monitor to see how much free space Ubuntu thinks it has. S.M. reports /home, /root, /tmp, etc. on sda5, despite the fact that Disks finds only four partitions. sda5 has no root directory (no '/'), but each top level directory (/home etc.) has total space 116.7 GB, 101.9 available, 8.9 used -- reasonable numbers, except that available+used!=total, and total is about 3 GB less than should be there.

What happened to the disk? Can I rescue it? If not, can I at least reinstall Ubuntu without wiping the disk and reinstalling Windows first? (I tried that once without doing anything special, and it didn't work. As I recall the system simply booted to Ubuntu; the dual-boot menu was gone.)

Comment: You post sdb2 & sdc3, do you mean your sda2 & sda3? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: You're right, sdb2 etc was a goof. When I installed boot-info apt-get hung after "Processing triggers for mim-support (3.60ubuntu1)." Boot-info ran though; URL is http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/X9zgTbVTqd/.  Also: I looked at source disk's partitions from a live DVD & it identified the Linux partition as /dev/sda5 not sda3. sda3 is the extended partition & there's no sda4, don't know why. I ran fsck on sda5 and it said everything's good. So did the disks utility's gear=>Check filesystem option.

Comment: Pastebin link not working. Primary partitions with MBR (msdos) are always 1 thru 4 and logicals always start at five. I have seen users with one primary sda1 as the extended and all logicals starting at sda5 (not really recommended). But I now use gpt and avoid the hassle of primary, extended & logical. Its just if dual booting with Windows in BIOS mode you must still use the now 35 year old MBR partitioning.